# Does IE modify the colors of my images?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8

I am very disappointed that my 3 hour template design is not cross-browser compatible. Why is this? well, because my header background color is not displaying correctly in IE:

I thought at first that the problem was created by a bad read of padding/margin or other metrics of Internet Explorer (but it was not, I checked and the metrics are perfectly fine)

The only problem is that IE somehow modifies the color of my header's background.

**Note:** This problem ONLY happens on Internet Explorer (I have tested on Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure why, but here is the CSS:

```
#header{
background:#5BA2D9 url('./images/header_bg.png') repeat-x left bottom;
min-height:90px;
}
```

**My question: does IE modifies the color of my images? Why? How can I avoid this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a result of color correction information in the PNG files.
Optimizing the PNG files should fix it.

See [here](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html) for more info.

Comment: The link couldn't be more useful! Thanks

Comment: Try http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ or http://punypng.com/ or http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/index.html

Comment: Thanks, (again), I feel bad I can only upvote 1 time. Edit: It worked, it is working on IE, your theory was accurate